# How can I get text on Python Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

```py
import scrapy


class WanikaniSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'japandict'
    allowed_domains = ['www.japandict.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.japandict.com/lists/jlpt5k']
    
           
    def parse(self, response):
        kanjiler = response.xpath("//div[@class='row']/div/div/div")
        for kanji in kanjiler:
            kanjiicon= kanji.xpath("//div[@class='row']/div/div/div/a/div/span")
            yield{
                'kanjiicon': kanjiicon
            }
```

I created spider like that. I wanna take `kanjiicon` as a text. But when I use `.get` `.extract` methods its returning empty.
How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm getting output.

CODE:

```
import scrapy


class WanikaniSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'japandict'
    allowed_domains = ['www.japandict.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.japandict.com/lists/jlpt5k']
    
           
    def parse(self, response):
        kanjiler = response.xpath('//*[@class="d-inline-block w-100 text-muted"]')
        for kanji in kanjiler:
            kanjiicon= kanji.xpath('.//*[@class="xlarge text-normal me-4"]/text()').get().replace('\n','').strip()
            
            yield {
                'kanjiicon': kanjiicon
            }
```

Output:

```
{'kanjiicon': '右'}
2021-08-22 05:58:27 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.japandict.com/lists/jlpt5k>
{'kanjiicon': '雨'}
2021-08-22 05:58:27 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.japandict.com/lists/jlpt5k>
{'kanjiicon': '円'}
2021-08-22 05:58:27 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.japandict.com/lists/jlpt5k>
{'kanjiicon': '下'}
2021-08-22 05:58:27 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.japandict.com/lists/jlpt5k>
{'kanjiicon': '何'}
2021-08-22 05:58:27 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.japandict.com/lists/jlpt5k>
{'kanjiicon': '火'}
2021-08-22 05:58:27 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.japandict.com/lists/jlpt5k>
{'kanjiicon': '外'}
2021-08-22 05:58:27 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.japandict.com/lists/jlpt5k>
{'kanjiicon': '学'}
2021-08-22 05:58:27 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.japandict.com/lists/jlpt5k>
{'kanjiicon': '間'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to decode the string to utf-8, ascii doesn't cover Japanese chars.

Try something like:

```
kanjiicon = kanjiicon.decode('utf-8')
```